# how to open datepicker dialog on click of edit text ANdroid?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

> I have a Fragment which extends Fragment, i want to open date picker dialog on click of edit text. i tried several ways but no expected result. Can anyone please help me out ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.maped);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new OnDateSetListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {

                    int s=monthOfYear+1;                                    
                    String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;                   
                    editText.setText(""+a);                                 
                }
            };

            Time date = new Time();
            DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(SignUp.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
            d.show();

            }
        });
```

i hope this will help you